# Phone no longer recognizes USB connection from computer

Tags: samsung, file-transfer, samsung-galaxy-s7, macos

Using a Samsung Galaxy S7 (Android 7.0) and a MacBook Air (macOS Sierra 10.12.5), I connect the phone's charging port to the computer's USB port. Neither the phone nor computer bring up any notifications.

I vaguely remember that I used to get a notification when I plugged the phone into the computer, saying they weren't compatible, but I may have opted to stop getting the notification since it happened every time, and I was just plugging it in to charge.

On my Mac I downloaded Android File Transfer, and on my phone I did Settings -> Developer Options -> USB Debugging, but nothing doing. Opening Android File Transfer gives the message "Please connect your Android device with a USB cable to get started.", even when it is indeed plugged in.

Anything I'm forgetting, or ideas for troubleshooting?

(As a note, my goal is to move things from icloud.com to my new android device. For example, I exported a vCard of my Contacts, and I want to move that to my phone to then import into Contacts, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some computers only recognize devices when they are plugged into the right usb ports. Have you tried using a different port? Also, some chords can be finicky, some of the cheaper ones don't like you when you try to do get into a device like that.

Comment: Using a different USB cable worked :)